# Plotting a sound signal

Tags: matlab, audio, plot, signal-processing, signals

I have a sound file, which I'll call sndfile.wav.
So far I have determined the number of samples, sampling rating, and the length in seconds.

```
[f,Fs] = wavread('mike.wav');
N = length(f);
slength = N/Fs;
```

Given that f is the vector containing the samples from the sound file, Fs is the sampling rate, N is the number of samples, and slength is the length of the sound file in seconds, how can I plot the sound signal with respect to time in seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a time vector and then plot it versus f.

```
t = linspace(0, N/Fs, N)
plot(t, f)
```

Answer (score 2):

moorepants answer is good for plotting the signal. If you want to do more to the signal after viewing take a look at the "Simple Audio Editor" available at file exchange. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19873-simple-audio-editor

It can read an audio file directly and display it. You can also play the signal and do cut,copy and paste with the audio signal.